# Godaddy, domains API, Automatic subdomain creation node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, dns, subdomain

my problem is that I can't create a CNAME record in DNS for my domain. I want to create subdomains through code using axios queries. But for some reason, I am constantly being told that the domain does not exist or the wrong zone file.

Code:

```
const axios = require('axios');

class Domains {
constructor(domain, apiKey, apiSecret) {
this.domainName = domain;
this.apiKey = apiKey;
this.apiSecret = apiSecret;
this.apiBaseUrl = 'https://api.ote-godaddy.com/v1';
}

    async createSubdomain(subdomain) {
        const headers = {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `sso-key ${this.apiKey}:${this.apiSecret}`
            }
        };
    
        try {
            const newRecord = [
                {
                    type: "CNAME",
                    data: this.domainName,
                    ttl: 600
                }
            ];
    
            const putResponse = await axios.put(`${this.apiBaseUrl}/domains/${this.domainName}/records/CNAME/${subdomain}`, newRecord, headers);
            
            if (putResponse.status === 200) {
                console.log(`Subdomain ${subdomain}.${this.domainName} successfully created`);
                console.log('Server response:', putResponse.data);
            } else {
                console.error(`Error creating subdomain: ${putResponse.status}`);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('An error occurred:', error.response ? error.response.data : error.message);
        }
    }

}

module.exports = Domains;
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KyT4.png)

I need to create automatically the subdomain for my domain via node.js script (axios or whatever stands for requests).